# How to JavaFx GridLayout Fill

Tags: javafx

I want to use the GridLayout in JavaFx which has two columns. Now I want a textfield in the second column to fill the maximal available space of the panel.

Everything I try gives me a non changing textfield size if I resize the window.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this:

**1.)** You can set the column percent width:

```
ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
col2.setPercentWidth(80);
```

**2.)** Or you use two VBox and use each one as a column.

Comment: I tried it with the percent width (seems to be easier) and it works, thx